# linux-compatible 802.11ac usb-adapter chipset

Tags: linux, drivers, 802.11

Are there any 802.11 usb-chipsets that have linux drivers available?

There are plenty of 802.11ac usb-adapters shipping already, but all I have seen only had windows support.

Comment: Did you find a model which does _not_ require any drivers outside of the Kernel?

Answer (score 7):

I can confirm that the edimax EW-7822UAC works under linux (using the driver downloaded from their website - http://www.edimax.com/en/support_detail.php?pd_id=479&pl1_id=28&pl2_id=138
(direct link http://www.edimax.com/images/Image/Driver_Utility/Wireless/NIC/EW-7822UAC/EW-7822UAC_linux_v4.2.2_7502.20130517.tar.gz)

Unfortunately the linux driver does not appear to support "monitor mode", so it's no use as a sniffer, though netmon can capture traffic under windows.

Comment: After kernel 3.10 there are some missing functions due to interface change.  I found this version works: https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, the only linux driver supporting 802.11AC networking is ath10k (see  http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath10k ), supporting Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac QCA98xx chipset. However no usb-adapter so far seems to support that chipset.

This doesn't necessarily give you an answer as I may be wrong, but after some research this is the only conclusion I came to. Any good news on this side are welcome.

Comment: But there are no Qualcomm devices in usb dongle form. If you know of any please provide the link. Until them I'm down voting you.

Comment: what about http://en.techinfodepot.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Linksys_WUSB6100M

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that edimax EW-7822UAC provide Linux driver. I successfully compiled its driver and connected it in Fedora 19. The download speed can reach average 15MB/s and peak 20MB/s by using perf.

This is the output of iwconfig and lsusb:

```
$ iwconfig
enp6s0u2  IEEE 802.11AC  ESSID:"Orz-5Ghz"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.2 GHz  Access Point: 74:D0:2B:41:EC:FC   
      Bit Rate:867 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=94/100  Noise level=0/100
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 7392:a822 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd
```

Answer (score 1):

There is quite an up-to-date table of OSS wireless stack drivers on Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_wireless_drivers#Driver_capabilities
As ow now, there seems to only one driver which is ac-capable at all and this one is *not* for USB devices.

The only possbility currently seems to use RTL8812AU based dongles. There are [quite some](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Special:Ask?title=Special%3AAsk&q=%5B%5BChip1+model::RTL8812AU%5D%5D&po=%3FInterface%0D%0A%3FForm+factor=FF%0D%0A%3FInterface+connector+type=USB+conn.%0D%0A%3FFCC+ID%0D%0A%3FManuf%0D%0A%3FManuf+product+model=Manuf.+mdl%0D%0A%3FVendor+ID%0D%0A%3FDevice+ID%0D%0A%3FChip1+model%0D%0A%3FSupported+802dot11+protocols=PHY+modes%0D%0A%3FMIMO+config%0D%0A%3FOUI%0D%0A%3FEstimated+year+of+release=Est.+year&eq=yes&p%5Bformat%5D=broadtable&order%5B0%5D=ASC&sort_num=&order_num=ASC&p%5Blimit%5D=500&p%5Boffset%5D=&p%5Blink%5D=all&p%5Bsort%5D=&p%5Bheaders%5D=show&p%5Bmainlabel%5D=&p%5Bintro%5D=&p%5Boutro%5D=&p%5Bsearchlabel%5D=%E2%80%A6+further+results&p%5Bdefault%5D=&p%5Bclass%5D=sortable+wikitable+smwtable)

Problem is, that it requires you to compile a kernel module manually.

Answer (score 0):

All available 802.11 chipset drivers you can see in kernel sources:

```
~# cd /path/to/your/kernel/sources
~# make menuconfig
```

then

```
Device Drivers  --->
    [*] Network device support  --->
         [*]   Wireless LAN  --->
                   ...
```

Just enable/disable yours and recompile kernel.

/path/to/your/kernel/sources depends on your OS: [linux kernel compilation](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux%20kernel%20compilation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)